# primeng editable table, issue pEditableColumn

Tags: html, angular, primeng-datatable

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zmmc89)

The output name does not contain a space(" ") even though I put a space before it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not Angular, however [it's behavior of the HTML specification:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html)

> In particular, user agents should collapse input white space sequences
>   when producing output inter-word space.

If you want to preserve whitespace in output, you can use the `<pre>` tag:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="output">
    <pre>{{rowData.name}}</pre>
</ng-template>
```

You can read more about `pre` tag here [at w3.org docs](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.4).